# Protocol Buffer Iteration is extremely slow in Azure function C#

Tags: c#, azure, performance, azure-functions

I am reading GTFS-RT Protocol Buffer messages from https url
It takes 10 minutes to iterate into tripupdates with approximately 2000 messages.

```
string url = "https://api.stm.info/pub/od/gtfs-rt/ic/v1/tripUpdates/";

WebRequest webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.Headers.Add("apikey", "xxxx");
FeedMessage feed = Serializer.Deserialize<FeedMessage>(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
    
foreach (FeedEntity entity in feed.entity)
     foreach (transit_realtime.TripUpdate.StopTimeUpdate ie in entity.trip_update.stop_time_update)
            ou = ou + "," + ie.stop_sequence + "";
```

I am wondering if we can read all streams once and iterate in memory instead of streaming one at the time.

** UPDATE***

here is the new code after modification Now second iteration does not add ie.stop_sequence to the same sb

requested output is supposed to be like

trip_id,route_id,start_time,start_date,vehicle.id,vehicle.label,vehicle.license_plate,stop_sequence1
trip_id,route_id,start_time,start_date,vehicle.id,vehicle.label,vehicle.license_plate,stop_sequence2
trip_id,route_id,start_time,start_date,vehicle.id,vehicle.label,vehicle.license_plate,stop_sequence3

or

```
Input:
A,B,C
     1
     2
     3

Output:
A,B,C,1
A,B,C,2
A,B,C,3

    _ = Parallel.ForEach(feed.entity, (e, state, index) =>
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(exploitant + ",");
        sb.Append(e.trip_update.trip.trip_id + ",");
        sb.Append(e.trip_update.trip.route_id + ",");
        sb.Append(e.trip_update.trip.start_time + ",");
        sb.Append(e.trip_update.trip.start_date + ",");
        sb.Append(e.trip_update.trip.schedule_relationship + ",");
        sb.Append((e.trip_update.vehicle == null ? "" : e.trip_update.vehicle.id) + ",");
        sb.Append((e.trip_update.vehicle == null ? "" : e.trip_update.vehicle.label) + ",");
        sb.Append((e.trip_update.vehicle == null ? "" : e.trip_update.vehicle.license_plate) + ",");
        foreach (transit_realtime.TripUpdate.StopTimeUpdate ie in e.trip_update.stop_time_update)
        {
            sb.Append(ie.stop_sequence + ",");
        }
        dictionary[index] = sb.ToString();
    });

    // do the final concatenation on the dictionary to maintain order.
    var ou = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, dictionary.Values);
```

**UPDATE2**

Result after running the new code

```
agency_id,entity_id,trip_id,route_id,trip_start_time,trip_start_date,schedule_relationship,vehicle_id,vehicle_label,vehicle_license_plate,stop_sequence
    "STM","225345768","225345768","406","15:32:00","20210225","SCHEDULED","","","","1"
,"2"
,"3"
,"4"
,"5"
,"6"
"STM","225364041","225364041","33","16:32:00","20210225","SCHEDULED","","","","1"
,"2"
,"3"
,"4"
```

what I am expecting is

"STM","225345768","225345768","406","15:32:00","20210225","SCHEDULED","","","","1"
"STM","225345768","225345768","406","15:32:00","20210225","SCHEDULED","","","","2"
"STM","225345768","225345768","406","15:32:00","20210225","SCHEDULED","","","","3"
"STM","225345768","225345768","406","15:32:00","20210225","SCHEDULED","","","","4"
"STM","225345768","225345768","406","15:32:00","20210225","SCHEDULED","","","","5"
"STM","225345768","225345768","406","15:32:00","20210225","SCHEDULED","","","","6"
"STM","225364041","225364041","33","16:32:00","20210225","SCHEDULED","","","","1"
"STM","225364041","225364041","33","16:32:00","20210225","SCHEDULED","","","","2"
"STM","225364041","225364041","33","16:32:00","20210225","SCHEDULED","","","","3"
"STM","225364041","225364041","33","16:32:00","20210225","SCHEDULED","","","","4"

Comment: which part of the code is taking time? `webRequest.GetResponse()`? Or `Serializer.Deserialize<FeedMessage>`? Can you separate that into multiple lines to be able to measure?

Comment: second foreach is taking time,When I iterate through entity is fast, however I need some data inside entity.trip_update

Comment: there is hundreds of trip_updates inside each entity, stream reading from website seems to be buttle neck, is there any way to read one shut and iterate in memory ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's because of streaming, but the time taken here is merely in the looping of hundreds of thousands of trip updates. Protobuf Serializer already reads the whole stream into memory while deserializing into C# objects (from `GtfsRealtimeBindings` nuget) `FeedMessage` which contains simply a `List` of `FeedEntity`, `TripUpdate` of each again contains a `List` of `StopTimeUpdate`. You can consider increasing throughput by parallelizing the loops.

UPDATE: To maintain the order you can capture the index of the source collection while iterating in parallel to update an in-.

```cs
            var dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<long, string>();
            _ = Parallel.ForEach(feed.Entities, (e, state, index) =>
            {
                // do stuffs
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append(e.TripUpdate.Trip.TripId);
                // ... and so on

                dictionary[index] = sb.ToString();
            });

            // do the final concatenation on the dictionary to maintain order.
            var ou = string.Join(",", dictionary.Values);
```

Also, I see you are doing string concatenation. You might want to consider `StringBuilder` for that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder#the-string-and-stringbuilder-types
https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/stringbuilder.html

Comment: changed the code , performance issue fixed , however result messed up

Comment: Updated the answer to maintain order in the resulted string

Comment: Thanks for update, I changed the code as bellow , there is still a small problem

Comment: and what is that?

Comment: I added an update to question with the modification and the issue

Comment: "Now second iteration does not add ie.stop_sequence to the same sb" - did you try to debug by putting a breakpoint there?

Comment: did you try to debug by putting a breakpoint there? – krishg 51 mins ago
i added the result after execution as UPDATE2 to the question Note : first iteration alone works fine , when I add the second one  as you see second iteration does not attach to the sb and it goes alone , I think because first one is in parallel and second iteration does not follow the same order

Comment: second iteration is for each entity within one isolated action of `Parallel.ForEach`. So, I don't think it would interfere. I did not actually get answer to my question yet "did you try to debug by putting a breakpoint there?"

Comment: You are right, I tried again , worked fine! thank you so much for your help!